# How to achive facebook kind of SSO in iOS sdk? (The way the opens a view for login and loading )

Tags: ios, objective-c, single-sign-on

How to achive facebook kind of SSO in iphone sdk?
(The way they open a view for login and loading).

I Don't want to use `UIViewController` and want to show *Login/Loading* view 
and want to put *Login/Loading* code at one place
as that view is going to be opened from lots of controllers.

Is there any way to achieve this? (protocol?)

Comment: Can you describe more what is Login/Loading view?

Comment: A view that will display Some entity's name where you going to Login. and Loading icon will appear if user is already logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but the following tutorial shows a handy mechanism for allowing you to design a popup overlay window using a UIViewController.

http://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/

You design a UIViewController in storyboard which contains your overlay popup view. The surroundings remain transparent. You can create an instance of this UIViewController in your code and then ask it to overlay its view onto your existing controller view. The result is a popup window similar to a UIAlertView, into which you can put whatever you wish.

I use this for doing popup help overlays, but I image you could easily use it for your facebook like content.

Benefit 1) Since you design it in a UIViewController, you can use all the size class related layout and you can see how it will look on all the different device types.

Benefit 2) It is totally reusable. From any controller, create an overlay UIViewController instance and ask it to overlay its content on your current controller. Reverse is to ask it to remove the overlay.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, UIViewController is not fitting in my requirement as SSO will happen from lots of controller and if I am using UIViewController then it will goes into the Navigation stack also.

Comment: From your post I got an idea to achieve this by using CustomView+Delegate. Will try and let you know if it's working.

Comment: You only use the UIViewController to make designing your layout easy, the right size for the screen and current orientation and make reuse simpler. It is never added to the navigation stack as you are not presenting or pushing it onto a stack. What happens is that you are taking the view from the controller and adding it on top of the view for your current controller. The reverse removes it. So it is really an easy way to overlay a custom view which I think is what you are about to try and do?